# I want to use regex notepad to displace a text from an expression that is in the middle of the text. For a better understanding, look at the example

Tags: notepad++

example:

this:

`into this ($$) business if not to ($$) save the world`

need this:

`save the world ($$) business if not to ($$) into this`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only one `($$)` marker would be occuring in the middle of the text, we can try a regex replacement with capture groups:

```
Find:    (.*) \(\$\$\) (.*)
Replace: $2 (\$\$) $1
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you my good friend, I will test it and see if it works

Comment: Thank you, dear friend, for helping me work.  I wanted to know if there is a way to have two $$ in the middle of the text and to move the sides and the text in the middle stays in place.

Comment: This is precisely what my answer is doing.  Did you bother to check the demo?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the demo

Comment: I am new, how can I rate you?

Comment: Dear friend, I apologize for bothering you. I have another problem in this regard, which I have left for you later. Please explain this to me, thank you.